# Normalize seeking value in SQL search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

*[PostgreSQL(9.4), Rails(4.1)]*

**The problem:**
I have a table with the names of tools. The `column_name` is `hstore` type and looks like this: `name -> ('en': value, 'de': value)`. Worth noting that 'de' is unnecessary in this problem, cause all names are stored only in 'en' key.
Next I have to construct a search query that will find the right record, but the format of the text in query are unknown, e.g.:

In DB:
`WQXZ 123GT`, should match query: `WQXZ_123-GT`

In DB:
`Three Words Name 123-D45`, should match query: `Three_WORDS_NAME 123D45`

and so on...

**Solution:**
To get this happen I want to normalize the value that I'm looking for and the query in such way that both of them will be identical. To do this I need to make both values in downcase, remove all whitspaces, remove all non-alphanumeric characters, so the values above will be:
`wqxz123gt == wqxz123gt`
and
`threewordsname123d45 == threewordsname123d45`

I have no problem to format a search value in ruby:

`"sTR-in.g24 3".downcase.gsub(/\s/, "").gsub(/\W/, "")  # => "string243"`

But I can't understand how to do this in SQL-search query to look like:

`Tool.where("CODE_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR(name -> 'en') = (?)", value.downcase.gsub(/\s/, "").gsub(/\W/, ""))`

Thank you for your time.

**UPD:** I can make a downcase in query:

`Tool.where("lower(name -> 'en') = (?)", value.downcase)`

But it solves only a part of the problem (downcase). The whitespaces and non-word characters (dots, dashes, underscores, etc.) are still an issue.

Comment: `("name -> 'en'  = ?", value.downcase.gsub(/\s/, "").gsub(/\W/, ""))` this one is not executeed?

Comment: No, because it will "normalize" only value. So "WQXZ_123-GT" would become "wqxz123gt", but it will not affect the value in DB - "WQXZ 123GT " because it will still be the same.

Comment: `("name -> 'en' = :value",value:  value))`

Comment: Nope, this is the same as the suggestion in the first comment (and only if the value is normalized somewhere before).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Postgres `replace` function to remove spaces. Then use `lower` function to match on that value. Like this.

```
Tool.where("lower(replace(name -> 'en', ' ', '')) = (?)", value.downcase.gsub(/\s/, "").gsub(/\W/, "") )
```

I hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Nitin Srivastava's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5580690/nitin-srivastava) answer directed me in right direction. All I needed was to use `regexp_replace` function.

So the proper query is:

```
Tool.where(
  "lower(regexp_replace((name -> 'en'), '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', 'g')) = ?",
  value.downcase.gsub(/\s/, "").gsub(/\W/,"")
)
```